# How to have wordpress in directory of flask app deployed to heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, url-routing

My flask app is deployed to heroku and all routes are working as expected.

I want the `example.com/blog` to load my wordpress that is hosted on different server. `example.com` and all routes are under flask app. And app is running with heroku.

Is it possible to point `example.com/blog` to different ip address?

I know that subdomain can do this job, but I am not fan of subdomains. As far as I know, it can be done via reverse proxy and I don't know how to set it up in heroku.

I'm using gunicorn web server.

Comment: Break down your question into smaller problems. Do you know how to execute your project (which is hosted on Heroku) locally and have `example.com/blog` point to your wordpress server? Are you happy with a simple http redirect? Your problem is unrelated to Heroku. First get it to run locally and then host on Heroku.

Comment: @TinNguyen my app is already deployed to heroku. And I want to install wordpress in directory of my app. And of course I tested it locally before deploying it.

Comment: So locally your app is already pointing to the wordpress server? Document those steps and then we can say why your configuration does not work on Heroku.

Comment: It's not pointing to WordPress server. And I don't want to redirect from /blog to SomeOtherDomain.com I just want the wordpress to appear in this directory ```myapp.com/blog```. Flask routers can redirect this URL to my different server which I don't want.

Comment: @TinNguyen Let's say you got custom tool built with react js or flask. And you deployed it to heroku and attached domain ```abc.com```. Now ```abc.com```'s URLs can be only managed by the app. But you can create ```sub.abc.com``` and point it to different IP with DNS. But in this case, I want the URL that is ```abc.com/blog``` to point to different IP. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Which gets me to my original point. Make it locally work that when you access e.g. `127.0.0.1:8080/blog` you see the wordpress page. I quote - break down your question into smaller problems. Because the entire solution is too complicated and there are a lot of moving parts in order to make it work. If one step fails the entire solution fails.